# To make authorization global instead of keeping it in every single HTTP Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have an API written in hapi.js where I have mentioned CRUD for the endpoints of an application. It checks for authorization using Accesstokenkey. Now I want to remove the redundant code and keep the authorizatio global. Is there any way to do it?

The code is mentioned below :

```
    async.series([function(callback(){
},
function(callback){
},],function(err,reply){
}
```

everytime only the service varies according to the request and module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use life cycle methods.
https://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle

Just check onPreAuth or onPostAuth methods.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't say much, do you want to set a default? If so check https://hapijs.com/api#serverauthdefaultoptions